# OS X upgrade on MacBook Pro mid 2010 trilemma

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, upgrade

I'd like to have some feedback from those of you who have experience to share about upgrading OS X on MacBook Pro 15" (mid 2010 - MacBookPro6,2).

I'm running OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard, and I've never needed to upgrade because I use my mac only for software development on the java environment, so I've never needed to stay up to date and I don't even have Apple or Android devices to sync. So, just consider the main use I do of my Mac is about developing on the java platform (ad just for fun).

Now I need to move to Java 7 or maybe Java 8 and I need to upgrade Snow Leopard to one of its successors:

- Mountain Lion (10.7.3 at least)
- Maverick
- Yosemite

Here's my trilemma: which of the aforementioned OS would better fit my laptop's hardware? According to Apple's official site all of them have the same minimum requirements:

- 2 GB of RAM
- 8 GB free HD space

Here's an excerpt from the System Profiler running on my laptop (translated from Italian localization):

- Model name:  MacBook Pro
- Model ID:    MacBookPro6,2
- Processor name:  Intel Core i5
- CPU speed:   2,4 GHz
- Number of CPUs:  1
- Number of cores: 2
- Cache L2 (per core): 256 KB
- Cache L3:    3 MB
- RAM: 4 GB

Please, don't point out the latter are free - I know - just focus on performance.

Personally, I don't feel like upgrading to Yosemite, but I'd rather move to Maverick. This is not based on figures, just on my gut feelings: I suspect that Yosemite may be too demanding about hardware configuration.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more advanced version, results in most memory consumption system. So, if you are only care about performance, no doubts, Mountain Lion must be your choice.